# htaccess issue with GET parameter

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i can't access my GET parameter due to htaccess.

my htaccess is following

```
RewriteRule ^search/?$ cms/productSearch.php?caller=search [NC,L]
```

and my url is

```
http://localhost/demo/search?src=a
```

how can i access both GET parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^search/?$ cms/productSearch.php?caller=search [NC,L,QSA]
```

`QSA` flag (Query String Append) is used to preserve existing query string while adding new query parameters.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)